# Closed subgroups of $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb C)$ with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{so}_n(\mathbb C)$

Tags: lie-groups, algebraic-groups

What is the classification of (Zariski) closed subgroups in $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb C)$ (viewed as a linear algebraic group) with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{so}_n(\mathbb C)$?

Is it true that every such group is a product of $\operatorname{SO}_n(\mathbb C)$ with a cyclic subgroup generated by $\mu I$, where
$\mu$ is some root of unity and $I$ is the identity matrix?

*Correction* in response to Mikhail Borovoi's [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/415156/closed-subgroups-of-mathrmgl-n-mathbb-c-with-lie-algebra-mathrmso-n#comment1064716_415156): Is it true that for $n \neq 8$ every such group is a product of either $\operatorname{SO}_n(\mathbb C)$ or $\operatorname{O}_n(\mathbb C)$ with a cyclic subgroup generated by $\mu I$, where $\mu$ is some root of unity and $I$ is the identity matrix?

Comment: No, the group $G={\rm O}_{2m}(\Bbb C)$ is not such a product.  Indeed, an element $g\in G$ with $\det(g)=-1$ acts on $\mathrm{SO}_{2m}(\mathbb C)$ by an outer automorphism. It follows that $g$ is not of the form $\mu I$.

Answer (score 3):

Such a subgroup contains $\mathrm{SO}_n(\mathbf{C})$ and is contained in the normalizer $N_n$ of $\mathfrak{so}_n(\mathbf{C})$.

What is $N_n$? It contains scalars acts on the 1-dimensional space of bilinear forms preserved by $\mathfrak{so}_n(\mathbf{C})$. It follows that $N_n=D\mathrm{O}_n(\mathbf{C})$ where $D\simeq\mathbf{C}^*$ is the group of scalars. If $n$ is odd, it follows that $N_n=D\mathrm{SO}_n(\mathbf{C})$ thus the description is exactly the one described: every closed subgroup with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{so}_n(\mathbf{C})$ is generated by $\mu\mathrm{Id}_n$ for some root of unity $\mu$.

If $n$ is even, it still holds that the possible groups are parameterized by finite subgroups of $D\mathrm{O}_n(\mathbf{C})/\mathrm{SO}_n(\mathbf{C})$. This group is abelian and is direct product of $D\mathrm{SO}_n(\mathbf{C})/\mathrm{SO}_n(\mathbf{C})\simeq\mathbf{C}^*$ by a group $W_2$ of order 2 (generated by any matrix of determinant $-1$ in $\mathrm{O}_n(\mathbf{C})$. So the resulting subgroups $H$ are parameterized by finite subgroups of $\mathbf{C}^*\times W_2$ and only those corresponding to a subgroup of $\mathbf{C}^\times \{1\}$ have the given form (generated by $\mathrm{SO}_n(\mathbf{C})$ and scalar matrices). In particular, $H/\mathrm{SO}_n(\mathbf{C})$ can be non-cyclic.

If $H$ contains $\mathrm{O}_n(\mathbf{C})$, it therefore happens that $H$ is generated by $\mathrm{O}_n(\mathbf{C})$ and $\mu I_n$ for some root of unity.

However when $n$ is even, it can happen that $H$ doesn't contain $\mathrm{O}_n(\mathbf{C})$, and also is not generated by $\mathrm{SO}_n(\mathbf{C})$ and scalar matrices. The simplest example is the group generated by $\mathrm{SO}_2(\mathbf{C})$ and the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}0 & i\\ i & 0\end{pmatrix}$ (note that this one is contained in $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{C})$).

(Note: $n=8$ is not a special case. Indeed, in general the "unusual" behavior of $\mathfrak{so}_n$ for $n=8$ disappears when $\mathrm{so}_n$ it is endowed with its standard $n$-dimensional representation.)

Comment: The question was modified from its original form (in response to @MikhailBorovoi's [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/415156/closed-subgroups-of-operatornamegl-n-mathbb-c-with-lie-algebra-mathfrak#comment1064716_415156)) to allow a subgroup generated by $\operatorname O_n(\mathbb C)$ and orthogonal matrices. \\ Is there any chance that "It contains scalars acts on the 1-dimensional space of bilinear forms preserved by $\mathfrak{so}_n(\mathbb C)$" is a typo?  I'm not quite sure how to parse it.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing special about $\mathbb C$ here except that it is a characteristic-$0$ field, so I will work over an arbitrary such field.

The identity component of a group $G$ with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{so}_n$ is $\operatorname{SO}_n$, so you're asking about the finite extensions of $\operatorname{SO}_n$ in $\operatorname{GL}_n$.

If $n = 1$, these are the finite subgroups of $\operatorname{GL}_1$, which are as you want.

If $n = 2$, these are the finite extensions of the (algebraic) torus $\operatorname{SO}_2$.  Note that $\operatorname{SO}_2$ is a maximal torus in $\operatorname{GL}_2$, hence self-centralising.  There is thus an injection from $\pi_0(G)$ to the Weyl group $\operatorname N_{\operatorname{GL}_2}(\operatorname{SO}_2)/{\operatorname{SO}_2}$, which is cyclic of order $2$.  It is easy to check that the representatives of the non-identity coset of the Weyl group lie in $\operatorname O_2$, so your conjecture works in this case.

There is an injection from $\pi_0(G)/{\operatorname C_G(\operatorname{SO}_n)}$ to $\operatorname{Out}(\operatorname{SO}_n)$, which, since $n \ne 8$, is cyclic of order $1$ (for $n > 2$ even) or $2$ (for $n > 2$ odd).

We have that $\operatorname C_G(\operatorname{SO}_n)$ is contained in $\operatorname C_{\operatorname{GL}_n}(\operatorname{SO}_n)$.  For $n > 2$, the latter equals $\operatorname Z(\operatorname{GL}_n)$ (as can be tested by computing with diagonal matrices, for example).  Thus, for $n > 2$ odd, we are done.

For $n > 2$ even (with $n \ne 8$), the inner-automorphism map is an isomorphism $\operatorname O_n/{\operatorname{SO}_n} \to \operatorname{Out}(\operatorname{SO}_n)$.  We thus have that $G$ is contained in $\operatorname Z(\operatorname{GL}_n)\cdot\operatorname O_n$, as desired.

Comment: @‍YCor's [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/415171) suggests that there is no need to treat $n = 8$ separately, but perhaps this Dynkin-diagram-focussed perspective, in the spirit of @‍MikhailBorovoi's [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/415156/closed-subgroups-of-operatornamegl-n-mathbb-c-with-lie-algebra-mathfrak#comment1064716_415156), is nonetheless of some minor value.